# Open popup div by entering the hash into the URL

Tags: jquery

I am building a site with a team page where each team member's bio is opened up inside a pop up div by clicking on a button. 
I've gotten as far as clicking on the button opens the pop up and clicking the 'x' closes it.

My problem is that only when entering the hash into the URL of the first member, does her popup appear. For the rest, this does not work. This needs to happen, as the URL is linked to from other pages.

All buttons containing the various hash hrefs have been given the class name 'open-team'. The following jQuery code works for the first team-member but not the rest. What am I missing here?

My code is as follows:

```
(function() {
  //open popup
  $(".open-team").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.team-info').next(".team-overlay").fadeToggle(); //When clicked, toggle visibility.
  });

  //close popup
  $(".team-close").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".team-overlay").fadeToggle(); //When clicked, toggle visibility.
    var location = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
    history.pushState('Meet The Team', 'Meet The Team', location);
  });

  //the problem code, where only the first pop up works, but not the rest
  if(window.location.hash == $(".open-team").attr('href')) {
    var href = window.location.hash;
    var open = $('a[href=' + href + ']');
    open.closest('.team-info').next(".team-overlay").show();
  }

})();
```

Comment: .attr() will only retrieve the value from the first matched element in the set, as per the jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/attr/). You perhaps need to check each one individually using a loop

Comment: Why do you need the `if` anyway? If there is no match link the `open` object will be empty and nothing will happen..

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ADyson! The loop suggestions helped a lot. I used the `each()` method which seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: @MoshFeu I used the `if` statement as it made sense to me, but please let me know if there is a different or easier of doing this. I am still getting to grips with jQuery, and any pointers are welcome.

Comment: I explained it in my answer. If you have any question let me know (You can also reach me via the social profiles in my profile page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need neither, the `if` check or loop `$.each` the links. You can just do something like:

```
$('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').
  closest('.team-info').next(".team-overlay").show();
```

Why?

Because unlike regular JavaScript, jQuery always return a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) (which is similar to an array, which means that if there is no element which match to the selector you supplied, the object will not `null` or `undefined` but an empty collection) object so if there is no link which match to the condition (of `href = location.hash`) nothing will happen.

If you will try to do this with regular JavaScript  (like `document.querySelector('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']')`) you will need to check if it exist bebore you can do anything to it.

You can see it in the demo below. Just change the `hash` in the URL and you could see the result.

http://output.jsbin.com/diqagom#link-b

If anything is not clear, let me know.

Comment: wow, thanks! That works perfectly, and with less than half the amount of code I used. Thank you so much, and thanks for the explanation. It all makes perfect sense :)

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ADyson for the suggestion! I've seemed to figure out a method that does work. Not sure if this is 100% compliant with jQuery rules, though, but it does seem to work 100%.

```
  $(".open-team").each(function() {
    if(window.location.hash == $(this).attr('href')) {
      var href = window.location.hash;
      var open = $('a[href=' + href + ']');
      open.closest('.team-info').next(".team-overlay").show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: yeah this works fine. What "rules" are you referring to?

Comment: @ADyson by "rules" I mean simply keeping to best jQuery practice.

Comment: well "best practice" is largely subjective, and AFAIK jQuery themselves don't publish anything specific on such a topic, though you can find blogs etc which claim to tell you...no doubt they will contradict each other in some aspects. But there's nothing obviously in your code above which is particularly "bad", in my personal opinion. Others may, of course, disagree.